# Why is this caught in running time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

**what is the problem with the following code?**

```
var results = db.Departments.Select(x => customfunction(x.DepartmentID));
results.toList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why this is this not caught in compile time but gives an exception in runtime?

There are many different LINQ providers that allow you to use LINQ against a variety of data sources (LINQ to Entities, LINQ to Objects, LINQ to XML among others).

Although LINQ to Entities does not know how to invoke your custom method (at least, not the providers for common databases), some LINQ providers might well understand how to execute `myfunction`.  The compiler is not integrated with all of the many LINQ providers, so the information as to whether your custom method can be included is only available at runtime.

In fact, LINQ to Objects can execute it

```
var results = db.Departments
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(x => myfunction(x.DepartmentID));
```

Comment: can you elaborate more? I did not understand yet..!

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of

```
db.Departments.Select(x => myfunction(x.DepartmentID));
```

to sql does not happen until very late in the process at runtime.

So at compilation time Entity Framework does not know that myFunction is not something it is not going to know how to convert to sql yet.

of course you could do

```
db.Departments.Select(x => (x * 2));
```

And EF will happily be able to translate to sql but if you try to use a custom property on Departments object that doesn't map to a field in the db or use a custom method that that the Linq data provider does not know how to translate to sql you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple: `.Select(x => myfunction(x.DepartmentID))` is never executed in C#. Instead, Entity Framework parses this expression and translates it to SQL.
For example, if you call `.Count()` in C# EF will translate this to `SELECT COUNT(...)`

This is all very powerful, except for a few cases such as yours.
EF analyzes your code through [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).
If you call `myFunction()` in an expression tree, it is impossible to "expand" that call to get the body of your function. This is a limitation of how C# is implemented. That's why EF is unable to generate sensible SQL, because it has no clue what your method does.

However, there is a reasonable alternative: [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

LinqKit will allow you to write "functions" that are reusable in your expressions.

Example:

```
static string[] QueryCustomers (Expression<Func<Purchase, bool>> purchaseCriteria)
{
    var data = new MyDataContext();

    var query = from c in data.Customers.AsExpandable()
                where c.Purchases.Any (purchaseCriteria.Compile())
                select c.Name;

    return query.ToArray();
}
```